# Looking for Nice Integrals

Tags: calculus

I encountered some integrals that seems easy to look at, but when evaluating it using a calculator, no matter what are the
lower and upper limits of the integrals that I choose, I always get a "MATH ERROR" message. I forgot what are those examples of integrals
that has those attributes, and what topic in calculus that covers these weird integrals.

My question is....

> 1. What are the examples of simple integrals that defy evaluation on the calculator if the upper and lower limits were choosen poorly?
> 2. What topic in calculus that deals with these types of integrals?

These integrals intrigued me for a while.

Comment: A simple example of an "un-evaluateable" integral I suppose would be $$\int^b_a \frac{1}{x} dx$$ given that $ab \leq 0$

Comment: I understand that you deal with definite integrals. But for impossibility results it is good also to be aware of **Liouville's theory** developed as early as the 1830's (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234799042_Integration_in_Finite_Terms_The_Liouville_Theory) for indefinite integrals

Comment: @BetaDecay almost there...but some integrals with positive upper and lower limits and some  integrals with negative upper and lower limits gives me a "MATH ERROR".......I like some examples of those cases......

Comment: @JeanMarie The integral that Beta Decay gives me were some of the integrals I'm looking for.....you can give me some examples too....hehehe.....Liouville's theory is pretty new to me and it might take me some time to understand it.....

Comment: @JeanMarie I need those types of integrals......

Answer (score 1):

An integral, where you might get this problem is $$\operatorname{li}(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\cfrac{1}{\log(t)}\mathrm{d}t.$$

I think the origin of the problem is easy to find. If $x>1$, $1$ is element of the interval $[0,x]$, which means that you have to divide by zero, since $\log(1) = 0$. A way to avoid an Error Message, is to either calculate the series representation of $\operatorname{li}(x)$ (you can find it on Wikipedia), or to write the integral with limits, so the boundaries would be $0$ and $1-\epsilon$ and $1+\epsilon$ and $x$, where $\epsilon$ tends to zero.